# Trouble using model properties of ViewModel in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I created a ViewModel that has two of my models as properties:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public Login loginVM;
    public Person personVM;        
}
```

The properties of the Login and Person objects are populated in the view by user input, but when I send my ViewModel back to my controller and try to use the Person/Login properties, it says they are returned as null:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPerson(ViewModel vm) 
{    
    DataBase da = new DataBase();
    da.addLogin(vm.loginVM);
    da.AddPerson(vm.personVM);    
}
```

both vm.loginVM and vm.personVM are null for some reason.

I found a blogpost where someone seemed to have come across this problem: https://garfbradazweb.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/mvc3-viewmodel-binding-to-controllerpost-methods/

but it really didn't seem to help at all

Comment: In case of GET, have you tried `ActionResult AddPerson([FromUrl] ViewModel vm)` and If its a POST: `ActionResult AddPerson([FromBody] ViewModel vm)`

Comment: I think `[HttpPost]` should be above the method not the VM!

Comment: Could you add your (CS)HTML code, so we can see if there's any wrong binding there?

Comment: @annemartijn I'm kinda scared to post all that code because this is a work project, but I'm binding by doing something like  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.personVM.first_name, "First Name:") or  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.loginVM.login_name, new { maxlength = "20" }) for all the properties of the models

Comment: Download Fiddler, see what's actually being sent back to the server... So download: http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler then head over to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540859/paypal-400-bad-request-more-specific/30541025#30541025 where I've shown how to use Fiddler to resolve another http related issue

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad that doesn't really seem to do anything. If it matters, I'm using Html.BeginForm() instead of Ajax.BeginForm() and I have more parameters for my ActionMethod, I just didn't think it'd be necessary to type them all so I created a simple example for what was happening

Comment: Since `first_name` is not capitalized, could it be a private field? It has to be a public property to be set from a POST.

Comment: all the fields being binded to the models are public @annemartijn

Comment: Interesting article you linked to.  I suppose you could do what the article suggests.  I think that would make you action look like public ActionResult AddPerson([Bind(Prefix = "Login")]Login login, [Bind(Prefix = "Person")]Person person).  However, I would suggest just using basic data types in you view models.  Rather then adding all that markup to your action parameters.

Comment: @ScottMacMaster what do you mean basic data types? Like not using actual models as ViewModel properties? because I've read in several places that you should use a ViewModel if you want to pass more than one model onto the view

Comment: int, string, datetime, etc.  Group them all in a class named something like AddPersonModel and use that as your model.

Comment: The main issue here isn't the question itself, but the lag of information to answer it. Discuss whether you can put this code online. I'm sure there will be a suitable answer then.

Comment: I figured out the problem. In the controller method I had to use( [Bind(Prefix = "personVM")] Person personModel, [Bind(Prefix = "loginVM")] Login loginModel ) as parameters, just like the article I posted in the opening post. However, before I was putting Bind(Prefix="Person") and Bind(Prefix="Login") instead of personVM and loginVM @annemartijn

Comment: You could self-answer your question to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In the controller method I had to use( [Bind(Prefix = "personVM")] Person personModel, [Bind(Prefix = "loginVM")] Login loginModel ) as parameters, just like the article I posted in the opening post. However, before I was putting Bind(Prefix="Person") and Bind(Prefix="Login") instead of personVM and loginVM

Answer (score 0):

your ajax call should look like this:

```
var model = {loginVM:{YOUR OBJECT}, personVM:{YOUR OBJECT}};
$.post(url,{vm:model});
```